# How can i add SCRAM-SHA-512 kafka config using Java API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I want to add new users to my kafka cluster, and the way to do it, seems to be by adding a SCRAM-SHA-512/256 config in the zookeeper database, but i only know how to do it using the command line utility, which will be something like this:

```
bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zookeeper_server_address --alter --add-config "SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=password]" --entity-type users --entity-name userName
```

Is there an alternative to approach this using the Kafka API for Java?

Answer (score 0):

I saw a thread where it says that the Kafka api doasn't comes with this functionallity, so i made a custom .sh script for creating users (create-user.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER=$1
USER=$2
PASSWORD=$3

if [ "x$SERVER" = "x" ] || [ "x$USER" = "x" ] || [ "x$PASSWORD" = "x" ]; then
    echo "usage: $0 <server:port> <user> <password>"
    exit
fi
bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper $SERVER --alter --add-config "SCRAM-SHA-512=[password=$PASSWORD]" --entity-type users --entity-name $USER
```

And i call it from java program:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("./create-user.sh", "zookeeper-server", "sampleUser", "password");
        pb.environment().put("PATH", "/home/myHome/Programs/java/jdk-13.0.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin");

Process p = pb.redirectErrorStream(true)
                .directory(new File("/home/myHome/Desktop/Kafka/kafka_2.12-2.4.1"))
                .start();
```

Notice, i needed to specify some directories in PATH and pass it as environment var to the ProcessBuilder because if not, it will throw erros saying that ther are commands that can not find